# Axios.delete() 419 unknown status

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, laravel-8

I have a list of products, but I get the following error when I try to delete one of them.

> DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/deleteProduct/2 419 (unknown status)

In postman, I get "CSRF token mismatch." This is my delete function.

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::find($request->id);
    $product->delete();

    return response()->json('Product deleted!');
}
```

**Vue method**

```
removeProduct(id)
{
    this.$store.dispatch('removeFromProducts', id)
}
```

**Vuex actions**

```
removeFromProducts({commit}, id){
        axios.delete(`/api/deleteProduct/${id}`).then((res)=>{
            commit('removeFromProducts', res.id)
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    },
```

**Vuex mutations**

```
removeFromProducts(state, id){
            let i = this.products.findIndex(data => data.id === id);
            state.products.splice(i, 1);
    },
```

By the way, i'm putting this in the head:

Comment: I don't think for delete you need to use `Vuex`. Also, you don't need `array.splice()` method. Check in Controller id is coming or not using dd() with postman. From Vue, you need to call the delete api with id parameter.

Comment: i tried it without vuex, i tried it in a lot of ways but it keep giving me the 419 status and the csrf token unmatched. i think it's not passing the id to the controller

Comment: Are you getting id correctly in Controller?

Comment: i figured it out, my mistake was i wrote route::post instead of route::delete in the api folder.